# Change a function at one point

Tags: coq

I have two elements `f : X -> bool` and `x : X`.

How to define `g : X -> bool` such `g x = true` and `g y = f y` for y != x.

Comment: Is equality over ``X`` decidable ? If it is not the case, it might not be possible to define such a ``g``, but you could always define a relation ``X -> bool -> Prop``

Comment: I use the "basic" equality (=) on X. For example, if X is the set of functions from nat to nat, `forall n, f n = g n` doesn't imply `f = g` a priori.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your answer to my comment, I don't think you can define a "function" `g`, because you need a constructive way do distinguish `x` from other instances of type `X`. However you could define a relation between the two, which could be transformed into a function if you get decidability. 
Something like:

```
Parameter X : Type.
Parameter f : X -> bool.
Parameter x : X.

Inductive gRel : X -> bool -> Prop :=
  | is_x : gRel x true
  | is_not_x : forall y: X, y <> x -> gRel y (f y)
.

Definition gdec (h: forall a b: X, {a = b}+{a <> b}) : X -> bool :=
  fun a => if h a x then true else f a.

Lemma gRel_is_a_fun: (forall a b: X, {a = b}+{a <> b}) ->
  exists g : X -> bool, forall a, gRel a (g a).
Proof.
intro hdec.
exists (gdec hdec); unfold gdec.
intro a; destruct (hdec a x).
now subst; apply is_x.
now apply is_not_x.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing Vinz's answer, there's no way of defining such a function for arbitrary `X`, because it implies that `X` has "almost decidable" equality:

```
Section Dec.

Variable X : Type.

Variable override : (X -> bool) -> X -> X -> bool.

Hypothesis Hoverride_eq : forall f x, override f x x = true.
Hypothesis Hoverride_neq : forall f x x', x <> x' -> override f x x' = f x'.

Lemma xeq_dec' (x x' : X) : {~ x <> x'} + {x <> x'}.
Proof.
  destruct (override (fun _ => false) x x') eqn:E.
  - left.
    intros contra.
    assert (H := Hoverride_neq (fun _ => false) _ _ contra).
    simpl in H.
    congruence.
  - right.
    intros contra.
    subst x'.
    rewrite Hoverride_eq in E.
    discriminate.
Qed.

End Dec.
```

This lemma says that if there's a way of doing what you asked for for `X`, then one can test whether two elements `x` and `x'` of `X` are equal, except that the proof of equality that one gets in the `true` case is actually a proof of the double negation of `x = x'`.